# Erro ao instalar Laravel: Pacote não disponível em versão estável

Tags: php, laravel

Estou seguindo estritamente o [indicado na documentação do Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#install-laravel) para fazer sua instalação:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Porém, depois de uma longa demora vem o seguinte retorno:

```
Changed current directory to (...)/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package lavarel/installer could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

O que eu posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Consegui baixar o pacote aqui. Não foi um problema pontual?

Comment: Problema pontual há dois dias. imagino que possa ser alguma restrição de rede então. Tem algum comando do composer que rastreia ou mostra o log da instalação?

Comment: Use o argumento `--verbose` para ver o log da progresso

Comment: Verifique se está tudo certo com o comando: `composer diagnose`

Comment: `composer diagnose` disse que está tudo ok. Já com o `--verbose` permaneceu exatamente o mesmo retorno... :(

Comment: Tentei aqui e funcionou bem! Tenta instalar da outra maneira (é como costumo fazer):

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Comment: @RicardoCruz, foi justamente o que eu fiz e resolveu a questão, agora o que causa o erro na primeira opção segue sendo um mistério.

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada no seu config.json ( geralmente em ~/.composer/config.json ) e verifique se não tem ( ou tinha - faz mais de um mês ) um parâmetro excluindo o packagist da lista de repositorios.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "packagist": false
    }
]
```

Colocando esse parâmetro no meu, consegui reproduzir o seu erro. Removendo ele instalou normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui reproduzir seu problema aqui. O comando funcionou perfeitamente. Tente os seguintes passos:

Atualize seu composer

```
composer self-update
```

Instale novamente o package, mas com uma regra de versão mais relaxada

```
composer global require 'laravel/installer=1.*'
```